# openssl: unkown digest sha-512

Tags: ssl, openssl, sha512

I try to create a certificate signing request with openssl:

```
openssl req -key my.key -out out.csr -new -subj "XXXXXXX" -config openssl-san.cnf
```

but get this error:

```
req: Unknown digest sha-512
req: Use -help for summary.
```

I'm working under Ubuntu 18.04, all files are there and are autogenerated, so I don't think the config or the key files are the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `openssl-san.cnf` configuration file to reference digest as `sha512` and not `sha-512`.

Have a look at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html

> `-digest`
>       This specifies the message digest to sign the request. Any digest supported by the OpenSSL dgst command can be used. This overrides the digest algorithm specified in the configuration file.

and

> `default_md`
>       This option specifies the digest algorithm to use. Any digest supported by the OpenSSL dgst command can be used. This option can be overridden on the command line. Certain signing algorithms (i.e. Ed25519 and Ed448) will ignore any digest that has been set.

If you look at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-dgst.html it tells you that you can run

```
openssl list --digest-commands
```

to see which digests, and their names, are available in your build of OpenSSL.

For example:

```
openssl list --digest-commands

blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4
md5               rmd160            sha1              sha224
sha256            sha384            sha512
```

Which are then the names you must use everywhere, on the command line or in your configuration files.